# Trying to do a Rundown in TSQL with Expiration Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, recursive-query

I'm trying to handle a rundown query in TSQL accounting for expired products.  I can do it with a while loop, but it's a little slow.  I would love to do it with set operators but I'm struggling to find a good method.  If anyone has some suggestions I would love to hear it.

Source Data, Inventory

```
cur_dt      exp_date    inventory   item    loc
2020-01-01  2020-01-02  10          1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-04  5           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-04  5           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-06  10          1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-08  5           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-10  5           1       1
```

Source Data, Consumption

```
cur_dt      cons_dt     consumption item    loc
2020-01-01  2020-01-01  3           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-02  3           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-03  7           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-04  7           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-05  4           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-06  4           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-08  15          1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-09  5           1       1
2020-01-01  2020-01-10  3           1       1
```

What I am looking for is a rundown, accounting for expired products.  The results don't have to match this, but it should give an idea of what I am looking for.

```
item    loc loctype dt          inv reqtoserve  served  expire  dos     remainconsume
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-01  37  3           3       0       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-02  34  3           6       0       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-03  23  7           13      4       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-04  16  7           20      4       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-05  12  4           24      4       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-06  8   4           28      4       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-07  8   0           28      4       1       0
1       1   WHSE    2020-01-08  0   15          36      4       0.53    7
```

I have working methods, the first using a recursive query, which works, but is a little slow and very complicated over lots of items.  Additionally, there have been issues with maxrecursion that I'd like to get away from.  I have tried replacing that with a while loop, but that is also slow when I start getting thousands of units.

I have tried using windowing functions to do this, but can't quite make it work.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to convert this logic to windowed functions/CTEs for TSQL or to make the while loop more efficient?

Here is the current While Loop iteration to demonstrate logic:

```
-- These are the parameters (when made a function)
declare @item int = 1
declare @loc int = 1
declare @loctype nvarchar(50) = 'WHSE'

-- Used in the calculation
declare @maxinv float
declare @expired float 
declare @curdt date
declare @curinv float
declare @served float
declare @totserved float
declare @rmcons float
declare @consume float
declare @dos float
declare @maxdt date

-- Define the starting inventory parameters
select @curdt = max(cur_dt),
@maxinv = sum(inventory),
@curinv = sum(inventory),
@served = 0,
@expired = 0
from BILL_RD_INVTEST
where item = @item
and loc = @loc

-- Deine the max date for the loop
select @maxdt = max(cons_dt),
@totserved = 0,
@rmcons = 0
from BILL_RD_CONSUME brc 
where item = @item
and loc = @loc

-- Check any Parameters [Debug Only]
-- select @curdt, @maxdt

-- Interate the loop (changed to handle long loops)
while @curdt <= @maxdt and @curinv <> 0
begin
    -- Get the consumption for the date
    select @consume = coalesce(consumption,0) 
    from dbo.BILL_RD_CONSUME 
    where item = @item
    and loc = @loc
    and cons_dt = @curdt

    -- Get the new max inventory for the date
    select @maxinv = coalesce(sum(inventory),0)
    from dbo.BILL_RD_INVTEST
    where item = @item
    and loc = @loc
    and exp_date >= @curdt

    -- Check if the max inventory is greater than the current inventory
    if @curinv > @maxinv
        begin 
            set @expired = @expired + (@curinv - @maxinv)
            set @curinv = @maxinv
        end
    
    -- Set the number served
    if @curinv > @consume
        begin
            set @served = @consume 
            set @curinv = @curinv - @consume
        end
    else
        begin
            set @served = @curinv
            set @curinv = 0
        end

    -- Set the remaining consumption
    set @rmcons = @rmcons + (@consume - @served)
    
    -- Set the total served
    set @totserved = @totserved + @served
    
    -- Calculate the DOS
    if @consume != 0
    set @dos = @served / @consume
    else set @dos = 1

    --select @item item, @loc loc, @loctype loctype, @curdt curdt, @maxinv maxinv, @consume consume, @curinv curinv, @totserved totserved, @served served, @expired expired, @dos DOS, @rmcons Remaing
    insert into dbo.BILL_RD_RESULTS values (@item, @loc, @loctype, @curdt, @curinv, @consume, @totserved, @expired, @dos, @rmcons)
    
    -- Reset variables in case there are days where there is no plan (assume 0 consumption)
    set @consume = 0
    set @served = 0

    -- Iterate to the next date
    set @curdt = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @curdt) 
end
```

Comment: It's a little hard to follow the nature of your data, not sure how you can have a consumption date ahead of a current date so would be good to elaborate.  But a technique to look at could be getting a calendar table (use a recursive CTE into temp table if needed), joining the two tables on date and then running parallel `sum() over()` window functions for the two data sets to get your cumulative consumption and expiration at a given point in time.

Comment: Sorry, they are all forecasts.

In one of the two methods I have gotten to work; one was a recursive CTE, but it essentially did the calculation like an accountant.  

Recurse so that Inventory matched to consumption.  Each inventory was decremented from based on the consumption.  If there was enough to fulfil consumption, then get the next consumption record.  If now, move to the next inventory row and continue until you run out of rows.